# Sending a range to a function

Tags: vba, excel

`enter code here`I'm having trouble sending a range to a function, it seems like it's sending an empty range though I know it is not.

This is where I call the function:

```
Dim rCellRange As Excel.Range
Dim nOfWords As Integer
Dim MyVal As String

findWordsResult = FindWords(rCellRange, nOfWords, MyVal)
```

Where rCellRange is a specific cell, let's say $A$1, nOfWords is an integer, and MyVal is the string with the words to look for.

This is the function:

```
Function FindWords(cellToSearch As Range, nOfWords As Integer, ParamArray words() As Variant) As Long

Dim counter As Long
Dim arr
arr = Split(cellToSearch)

Dim word, element

If UBound(arr) > 0 Then
    For Each word In words
        For Each element In arr
            If word = element Then counter = counter + 1
        Next
    Next
Else
    ' cell to search is empty
    counter = 0
End If

If counter = nOfWords Then
    FindWords = 1
Else
    FindWords = 0
End If

End Function
```

It always returns FindWords = 0 even though I know it should be 1. I have checked the incoming parameters and nOfWords and MyVal is transferred correctly, but rCellRange seems to be empty.

Where is the problem?

**EDIT:**
Maybe I should paste the complete code instead of parts of it. I know there's a lot of ugly solutions, but I'm no expert so... Here is the complete code:

```
  Sub Set_Hyper()

 '   Object variables
Dim wks As Excel.Worksheet
Dim rCell As Excel.Range, testRange As Excel.Range, rCellRange As Excel.Range
Dim fFirst As String, splitSearch As String, MyVal As String
Dim nOfWords As Integer, findWordsResult As Integer, oneWord As Integer
Dim i As Long

 '   Sätt det inmatade ordet som sökord
MyVal = ActiveSheet.Range("D9")
Set testRange = ActiveSheet.Range("D9")

' Ränka antalet inskrivna ord och dela upp söksträngen i flera ord
nOfWords = COUNTWORDS(testRange)
If nOfWords > 1 Then
    splitSearch = Split(MyVal)(0)
Else
    splitSearch = MyVal
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

' Rensa resultatlistan från förra sökningen
Application.Volatile (False)
Worksheets("Start").Range("D19:H99").Clear

' Sätt vit bakgrund på sökresultatet
Range("D19:H99").Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With

i = 19
 '       Begin looping:
For Each wks In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
     If wks.Name <> "Start" Then

        With wks.Range("A:E")

            Set rCell = .Find(splitSearch, , , xlPart, xlByColumns, xlNext, False)
         '           If something is found keep going
            If Not rCell Is Nothing Then
             '               Store the first address
                fFirst = rCell.Address
                Set rCellRange = Range(rCell.Address)

                If nOfWords > 1 Then
                findWordsResult = FindWords(rCellRange, nOfWords, MyVal)
                Else
                End If

                ' Ta reda på i vilken kolumn resultetet finns i och visa resultatet
                If findWordsResult = 1 Or nOfWords = 1 Then

                Do

                    If rCell.Column() = 1 Then
                    ' Link to each cell with an occurence of {MyVal}
                    rCell.Hyperlinks.Add Cells(i, 4), "", "'" & wks.Name & "'!" & rCell.Address, TextToDisplay:=rCell.Value
                    rCell.Offset(0, 1).Copy Destination:=Cells(i, 5)
                    rCell.Offset(0, 2).Copy Destination:=Cells(i, 6)
                    rCell.Offset(0, 3).Copy Destination:=Cells(i, 7)
                    rCell.Offset(0, 4).Copy Destination:=Cells(i, 8)
                    Set rCell = .FindNext(rCell)
                    i = i + 1 'Increment our counter

                    End If

                    If rCell.Column() = 2 Then
                    ' Link to each cell with an occurence of {MyVal}
                    rCell.Hyperlinks.Add Cells(i, 4), "", "'" & wks.Name & "'!" & rCell.Address, TextToDisplay:=rCell.Offset(0, -1).Value
                    rCell.Copy Destination:=Cells(i, 5)
                    rCell.Offset(0, 1).Copy Destination:=Cells(i, 6)
                    rCell.Offset(0, 2).Copy Destination:=Cells(i, 7)
                    rCell.Offset(0, 3).Copy Destination:=Cells(i, 8)
                    Set rCell = .FindNext(rCell)
                    i = i + 1 'Increment our counter

                    End If

                    If rCell.Column() = 3 Then
                    ' Link to each cell with an occurence of {MyVal}
                    rCell.Hyperlinks.Add Cells(i, 4), "", "'" & wks.Name & "'!" & rCell.Address, TextToDisplay:=rCell.Offset(0, -2).Value
                    rCell.Offset(0, -1).Copy Destination:=Cells(i, 5)
                    rCell.Copy Destination:=Cells(i, 6)
                    rCell.Offset(0, 1).Copy Destination:=Cells(i, 7)
                    rCell.Offset(0, 2).Copy Destination:=Cells(i, 8)
                    Set rCell = .FindNext(rCell)
                    i = i + 1 'Increment our counter

                    End If

                    If rCell.Column() = 4 Then
                    ' Link to each cell with an occurence of {MyVal}
                    rCell.Hyperlinks.Add Cells(i, 4), "", "'" & wks.Name & "'!" & rCell.Address, TextToDisplay:=rCell.Offset(0, -3).Value
                    rCell.Offset(0, -2).Copy Destination:=Cells(i, 5)
                    rCell.Offset(0, -1).Copy Destination:=Cells(i, 6)
                    rCell.Copy Destination:=Cells(i, 7)
                    rCell.Offset(0, 1).Copy Destination:=Cells(i, 8)
                    Set rCell = .FindNext(rCell)
                    i = i + 1 'Increment our counter

                    End If

                    If rCell.Column() = 5 Then
                    ' Link to each cell with an occurence of {MyVal}
                    rCell.Hyperlinks.Add Cells(i, 4), "", "'" & wks.Name & "'!" & rCell.Address, TextToDisplay:=rCell.Offset(0, -4).Value
                    rCell.Offset(0, -3).Copy Destination:=Cells(i, 5)
                    rCell.Offset(0, -2).Copy Destination:=Cells(i, 6)
                    rCell.Offset(0, -1).Copy Destination:=Cells(i, 7)
                    rCell.Copy Destination:=Cells(i, 8)
                    Set rCell = .FindNext(rCell)
                    i = i + 1 'Increment our counter

                    End If

                    ' Test att skapa vit bakgrund
                    With Selection.Interior
                        .Pattern = xlSolid
                        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
                        .TintAndShade = 0
                        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
                    End With

                Loop While Not rCell Is Nothing And rCell.Address <> fFirst

                Else

                End If
            End If
        End With
     End If
Next wks
 '   Explicitly clear memory
Set rCell = Nothing
 '   If no matches were found, let the user know
If i = 18 Then
    MsgBox "The value {" & MyVal & "} was not found on any sheet", 64, "No Matches"
    Cells(1, 1).Value = ""
End If
 '   Reset application settings
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Here is the COUNTWORDS function:

```
Function COUNTWORDS(rRange As Range) As Long

Dim rCell As Range
Dim Count As Long

For Each rCell In rRange

   lCount = lCount + Len(Trim(rCell)) - Len(Replace(Trim(rCell), " ", "")) + 1

Next rCell

COUNTWORDS = lCount
```

End Function

Comment: You called `rCellRange` as `Excel.Range` and then send it to function. However function is looking for `cellToSearch` which you did not called anywhere...

Comment: `If UBound(arr) > 0 ` This will evaluate to false if you `Split` non-space delimited word (Ubound(arr) = 0, you only got one word). So counter = 0 and thus Findwords = 0.

Comment: But it doesn't matter what I call the range outside the function, I still send the range to the function and what the range is called inside the function is of no interest. Right?

Comment: That's a good comment @L42 but it's the same result with two or more words.

Comment: Also your nOfWords, it should be updated when you change the formula. Otherwise it will be zero. I don't know why you put such argument when the purpose of your function is to count words. Btw, how do you want to enter your search words? Value1,Value2,Value3... and so on?

Answer (score 1):

Try this which seems to works for me.

```
Option Explicit
Function FindWords(cellToSearch As Range, ParamArray words() As Variant) As Long
    Dim counter As Long
    Dim arr As Variant

    If Not IsEmpty(cellToSearch) Then
        arr = Split(cellToSearch)
    Else
        FindWords = 0
        Exit Function
    End If

    Dim word As Variant
    For Each word In words
        If Not IsError(Application.Match(word, arr, 0)) Then
            counter = counter + 1
        End If
    Next
    FindWords = counter
End Function
```

**Result in Worksheet:** 
1-word search

[image]

2-word search

[image]

**Result in VBA:**

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim myval
    myval = Array("Foo", "bar")

    i = FindWords(Range("A1"), myval(0), myval(1))
    'i = FindWords(Range("A1"), "Foo", "bar")
    Debug.Print i '~~> this returns 2 for both line code above
End Sub
```

Remember when you use *ParamArray*, you need to specify each element you want to pass in the array.
If this is somewhat different than what you want then update your question. HTH

Answer (score 0):

Your function is working fine but

1. You are not supplying any valid range into the function when called.
2. May be the CASE of your search is different from what is actually there in Excel

See my edits:

```
Public Sub test()
Dim rCellRange As Excel.Range
Dim nOfWords As Integer
Dim MyVal As String

'BEFORE RUNNING THIS, please put "The Big Blue Fox Flew over the cuccoo nest" in to the cell A1
Set rCellRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Range("A1")
nOfWords = 1
MyVal = "Fox"
findWordsResult = FindWords(rCellRange, nOfWords, MyVal)

MsgBox findWordsResult

End Sub

Function FindWords(cellToSearch As Range, nOfWords As Integer, ParamArray words() As Variant) As Long

    Dim counter As Long
    Dim arr
    arr = Split(cellToSearch)

    Dim word, element

    If UBound(arr) > 0 Then
        For Each word In words
            For Each element In arr
                'If you want to make this case insensitive, use: If UCase(word) = UCase(element) Then counter = counter + 1
                If word = element Then counter = counter + 1
            Next
        Next
    Else
        ' cell to search is empty
        counter = 0
    End If

    If counter = nOfWords Then
        FindWords = 1
    Else
        FindWords = 0
    End If

    End Function
```

Comment: Yes that seems to be the problem, that my rCellRange is empty, but since it is not a fixed cell I cannot specify the range as you have done here. It is the search function which finds the cell and I am trying to set the address from that cell to rCellRange and pass it on to the function. Please see my edited question above.